# Radiative Transfer Equation in Earth Engine for LST from Landsat 8

Tags: google-earth-engine, qgis-3, landsat-8, land-surface-temperature

I'm using the following code in earth engine to calculate LST from Landsat image. I want to use Radiative Transfer Equation to use in this, but I know how to code that in GEE. Please Help!

```
var col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .map(maskL8sr)
  .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31')
  .filterBounds(roi)
var image = col.median()
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')
var thermal = image.select('B10').multiply(0.1)

var min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))

var max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))

var fv = ndvi.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))
  .pow(ee.Number(2))
  .rename('FV')

var a = ee.Number(0.004)
var b = ee.Number(0.986)
var EM = fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM')
var imageVisParam3 = {
  min: 0.9865619146722164,
  max: 0.989699971371314
}
var LST = thermal.expression(
  '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
    'Tb': thermal.select('B10'),
    'Ep': EM.select('EMM')
  }).rename('LST')
```

Code:https://code.earthengine.google.com/ff1e545a9bd47124fc359e9ef32886b7